# how to quit describe-key function?

Tags: key-bindings, quitting, builtin

I forgot what a key is bound to, so I decided to run

```
C-h k <my key binding>
```

But after pressing `C-h k`, I've remembered about that key binding and decided to quit. So I pressed `C-g`. Instead of quitting that command, `describe-key` described about `C-g`. I tried various other quit functions but they didn't work. I am wondering how to quit `describe-key`?

Comment: Assuming there were a keybind for quitting `describe-key` , how would you describe that keybind with Emacs?

Comment: As stated, the question makes little sense - I'm voting to close it as unclear. But my guess is that you have another, *real* question behind this one - if so, please edit your question to state it clearly. What are you *really trying to do*, and in what way does `C-h k` not seem to help you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot quit the `describe-key` command. The reason is simple: it cannot know whether you changed your mind about requiring a description of a key or whether you want a description of the key <kbd>C-g</kbd>. So it assumes it's the latter, because otherwise it would be impossible to get a description of that key.

You will just have to live with the `*Help*` buffer being displayed in some window. Usually you should be able to make the window/buffer go away by pressing <kbd>C-x o</kbd> and then <kbd>q</kbd>. Or you could just use <kbd>C-h c</kbd> (`describe-key-briefly`) instead. That doesn't create a window.